# Android - How to check for button click in a custom alert dialog box?

Tags: java, android, user-interface, android-dialog, flat

I've got two buttons: Share, Continue. Both of them are created in a new XML file because I wanted to keep my application with a nice flat Windows 8/10 looking GUI.

I am able to display the dialog message, but the problem I am facing is, how can I check which button was clicked by the user: Share or Continue? I can't set up the onClickListener for them because this alert dialog has been created in a new file, thus, it crashes the app if I try to do so.

Here's the XML code for the buttons:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/share_button"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:text="SHARE"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_blue" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/continue_button"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:text="CONTINUE"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_green" />
```

And the java code where I display this as an alert dialog:

```
Dialog d = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
d.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
d.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
d.show();
```

Comment: I didn't get what you meant by "created in a new file, thus, it crashes the app". What happens when you try to find the buttons by their ids `d.findViewById(R.id.continue_button);`?

Comment: Nothing happens when I do it like that. But what's the use of that anyway? I mean, if that's how I find the ID of the button, how do I set up the onClickListener then?

Comment: You already have the ids of your buttons. `Dialog.findViewById()` returns you a corresponding `View` for which you can set a listener: `view.setOnClickListener(...);`.

Comment: Initialise your button as Android777 suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call it by your `dialog d` i.e :

```
    Dialog d = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
    d.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    d.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
    Button button = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.share_button);
    Button button2 = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.continue_button)
    d.show();
```

And then you can make a normal `onClickListener`

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View v) {
      //STUFF
  }
});
```

Hope it helps ;)